# Firebase device breakdown only shows "iPhone"

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, device

I'm trying to understand what devices our users use our app with. With Android it works fine—I'm able to add "Android" as a filter and get a full breakdown of all the models used—but trying to do the same for iOS, it seems like a majority of the devices only show as "iPhone". Adding another filter ("device model = iPhone") or downloading the csv doesn't help as it's not further segmented.

Does anyone know if "iPhone" is referring to a specific model? Or if there is any way I can segment this further?

Thanks!

[image] [image]